# Can not navigate while app is in background

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I use Navigation Component to navigate between fragments.

Init navigation in main activity:

```
val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.nav_graph)
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, navHostFragment)
        .commit()
```

Navigation to another fragment in splash fragment:

```
findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToHomeActivity())
```

In splash i do auth, it takes some time, after auth i navigate to home fragment.
If i minimize app (press home button) in splash fragment then navigate() doesn't work and when i open app again it remains in splash fragment

In console:

```
NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination my.app/homeFragment as it was not found on the current back stack
FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get your auth callback, test if your app is in foreground and if so, navigate. Do nothing if your app is in background.

In the onResume method of the splashscreen, test if your user is authenticated. If so, skip your splashscreen.

Comment: Yeah, i do that. But i think it's a bad and stupid way.

Comment: That's some argument!
Then let you help yourself

Comment: Sorry, i didn't want to offend u. I meant that i used same solution, but it seemed to me that this is a bad way

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution would be to detach the navigation component on onPause.
While the navigation logic is not available, add those navigation actions to a queue.

When you resume, restore the navigation component and execute all the pending actions in the queue.